# first-letter initial quote doesn't work in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-content

I quite dont get it here, firefox doesn't want to accept ❝ (U-275D) as my first letter dispite the fact that they are supposed to accept initial quote.

Does anybody have any idea ? http://jsfiddle.net/DXn3B/1/

```
.who
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:lighter;
    color:#565656;
    font-size:1em;
}

.who:first-letter
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
}

.who:before
{
    content: '\275d';
    color:#272727;
}
.who:after
{
    content: '\275e';
    color:#272727;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-family: 'Coverdale-Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation `'\275d'` denotes U+275D HEAVY DOUBLE TURNED COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT, which has General Category So [Symbol, Other]. Hence, the CSS 2.1 [rule on `:first-letter`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#x50) does not apply to it:

> “Punctuation (i.e, characters defined in Unicode [UNICODE] in the "open" (Ps), "close" (Pe), "initial" (Pi). "final" (Pf) and "other" (Po) punctuation classes), that precedes or follows the first letter should be included”.

Answer (score 0):

You could try put them as text:

```
.who:before
{
    content: '❝';
color:#272727;
}
.who:after
{
content: '❞';
color:#272727;
font-size: 2.5em;
font-family: 'Coverdale-Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yahyaKACEM/DXn3B/2/).
Try this [site](http://copypastecharacter.com/punctuation) for more cool stuff.

Comment: Why do you think this makes any difference?

Comment: check the jsfiddle you'll see.

Comment: I checked, it makes no difference. Did you check it yourself?

Comment: On firefox there's no difference.

Comment: Makes no difference for me unfortunatly :/

Answer (score 0):

I can’t see why you are using both `.who:first-letter` *and* `.who:before` here. (`.who:before` already allows you to format the content you are inserting almost any way you like, so using `:first-letter` as well is kinda redundant, or in this case, maybe even the cause of the error.)

Add the declaration you have set for the first one into the rule for the latter (and delete the first completely), then you should get what you want.

Comment: Depending on the use case, `:first-letter` can still match the first letter of `:before` if the `:before` is generated inline within the element's context. That said, it may well be the cause of the error, depending on the character being used versus just using `open-quote`.

Answer (score 0):

Really, I have no idea why it doesn't work. But maybe that's somewhere near your desired result. http://jsfiddle.net/DXn3B/4/
I used the `:before` itself instead of `:first-letter` and it works fine. Maybe those two aren't meant to work together like that.